# Pass pandas dataframe to print

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to pass a dataframe element to a formatted print note that I am testing to later send in an email.

I am trying to take the last row's data under column "Notes:" and inserting it into the print function as you can see below:

```
def report(data):
  print("""
  Cash up by: 
  Card: 
  Cash: 
  Variance: 
  Total: 
  Petty Cash: 
  Director Tab: 
  Comp Total: 
  Wastage: 
  Notes: %s
  Tank Notes: 
  Close Checks Performed: 

  """, %(data["Notes:"].iloc[-1]))
```

But my error comes out:

```
 File "<ipython-input-25-d11d0a250495>", line 16
""", %(data["Notes:"].iloc[-1]))
```

^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you try `.to_html` method. It generates html-formatted table, that could be later sent by email.

Comment: You should remove the comma at `""", %(data...`

Comment: Thanks @bubble! Great suggestion. Implemented this!